# How to remove slider bar in HTML CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have some images that I want to slide horizontally when I press a button, I have managed to show my images as I want but I'm annoyed by that gray sliding bar below my images, I want to remove it and I do not know how to do it, I hope you can help me, thanks.

part of my html code :

```
<div class="image-container">
        <div class="scroll-wrapper">
          <div class="image-list">
            <img src="./img/seller1.png">
            <img src="./img/seller2.png">
            <img src="./img/seller3.png">
            <img src="./img/seller4.png">
            <img src="./img/seller5.png">
            <img src="./img/seller6.png">
            <img src="./img/seller7.png">
            <img src="./img/seller8.png">
            <img src="./img/seller9.png">
            <img src="./img/seller10.png">
            <img src="./img/seller11.png">
            <img src="./img/seller12.png">
          </div>
        </div>
```

part of my css code :

```
.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;

}

.scroll-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.image-list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  
}

.image-list img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

I want to remove the slider bar, I want to remove it from my page, I have tried to make the images I have added to slide and I have succeeded, but I want them to slide using a button, but that is a problem for later, right now I am waiting for help to delete that slider bar.